# Making operator<< virtual?

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading, virtual

I need to use a virtual << operator. However, when I try to write:

```
virtual friend ostream & operator<<(ostream& os,const Advertising& add);
```

I get the compiler error

> Error 1 error C2575: 'operator <<' :
>   only member functions and bases can be
>   virtual

How can I turn this operator virtual?

Answer (score 103):

The problem with this setup is that the `operator<<` you defined above is a free function, which can't be virtual (it has no receiver object).  In order to make the function virtual, it must be defined as a member of some class, which is problematic here because if you define `operator<<` as a member of a class then the operands will be in the wrong order:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    virtual ostream& operator<< (ostream& out) const;
};
```

means that

```
MyClass myObject;
cout << myObject;
```

will not compile, but

```
MyClass myObject;
myObject << cout;
```

will be legal.

To fix this, you can apply the Fundamental Theorem of Software Engineering - any problem can be solved by adding another layer of indirection.  Rather than making `operator<<` virtual, consider adding a new virtual function to the class that looks like this:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    virtual void print(ostream& where) const;
};
```

Then, define `operator<<` as

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const MyClass& mc) {
    mc.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

This way, the `operator<<` free function has the right parameter order, but the behavior of `operator<<` can be customized in subclasses.

Comment: thanks it is very helpful. i thought a bout this solution,but i thought maybe There is another way that I do not know that easier for implementation.

Comment: *"any problem can be solved by adding another layer of indirection"* - remember, any problem except the problem of too many layers of indirection ;)

Comment: @Kos:  No, no.  As long as you've declared it `unsigned indirection;`, you just have to keep adding more and more indirection and the problem will solve itself when you roll over

Answer (score 42):

You define your operator << to call a virtual print method:

```
class Base
{
    protected:
        virtual void print(std::ostream& str) const = 0;
    public:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, Base const& data)
        {
            data.print(str);
            return str;
        }
}
```

Comment: you probably meant `data.print(str);`

Comment: In addition to @Gene's comment, the pure virtual function needs to be protected so that non-friend derived classes can implement it.

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien: You could just as easily leave it as private and it will still be implementable. But I agree protected is probably a good idea.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't think that that was legal, but it apparently works:  http://codepad.org/NGOA87Bn

Comment: @Daniel Trebbien: In the derived class it can be public or private and it will still work (Java/C# are more strict about this. You can not make something less protected in a derived class). Though it is considered bad practice to make the access less restrictive in a derived class.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you really want to provide output functionality for a hierarchy of classes, and if so, you can provide a `friend operator <<` that calls a `virtual` function.

```
class Parent
{
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Parent& p);
    // ... other class stuff
protected:
    virtual void printMyself(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        // do something if you must, or make this a pure virtual
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Parent& p)
{
    p.printMyself(os);
    return os;
}

class Child : public Parent
{
    // other class stuff...
protected:
    virtual void printMyself(std::ostream os) const
    {
        // whatever you need to do
    }
};
```

Also detailed in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.11)