# access overloaded template functions

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading, typename

hey guys,
i'm confused as to how to access an overloaded template function like this one:

```
 template <typename T>
 friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Matrix& right)
 {
      for(int i=0; i<right.rows*right.cols; i++)
        cin >> right.elements[i];
 }
```

with a function such as:

```
 template <typename T>
 Matrix(T r, T c) {rows=r; cols=c; elements=new T[r*c];}
```

i was able to do

```
 Matrix <double> test(number, number)
```

for example, but i have no idea how to use a templated >> operator (or << or * or +..)  any help would be appreciated.  thanks!

Comment: You need to add more context, in particular the class template declaration, including the member attributes and the existing code *where it actually is* in the class template (or out of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you are declaring a class template `Matrix` that has a type argument `T`, and that you want to use the defined `operator>>` (you should make this more explicit in the question):

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix {
   int rows, cols;
   T* elements;
public:
   Matrix( int c, int r );        // Do you really want the number of 
                                  // rows/columns to be of type `T`??

   // Note: removed template, you only want to befriend (and define)
   // a single operator<< that takes a Matrix<T> (the <T> is optional
   // inside the class braces
   friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& i, Matrix& m )
   {
       // m.rows, m.cols and m.elements is accessible here.
       return i;
   }
};
```

And then it is quite simple to use:

```
Matrix<double> m( 1, 2 );
std::cin >> m;
```

That is not the only option, it is just the most common one. That is in general a class template can befriend a single (non-templated) function (think `operator<<` and `operator>>` as functions) as in the code above, or it might want to befriend a function template (all instantiations) or a particular instantiation of a function template.

I wrote a long explanation of the different options and behaviors [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class/4661372#4661372), and I recommend you to read it.

Comment: sorry, this didn't work.  it claims that right.cols, right.rows...are inaccessible without the template typename T line

Comment: @pauliwago: You should really add the enclosing class template declaration and the member declarations with the context. Else you are asking to search for an object in a room with the lights off. Are you defining the operator inside the `Matrix` class template?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the only way to access is something like this:

```
operator>> <YourType> (istream, param);
```

but it of course defeats all the advantages of operator overloading. So there is something wrong with this operator definition. Maybe Matrix is a template type and it should be

```
template <typename T>
operator>>(istream & in, Matrix<T> & right);
```

I see no use of template parameter in your operator definition, so something is wrong with it.