# How to make template function friend of template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a template class with private constructor and destructor:

```
template <typename T>
class Client
{
    private:
        Client(...) {}
        ~Client()   {}

        template <typename U>
        friend class Client<T>& initialize(...);
};


template <typename T>
Client<T> initialize(...) 
{
      Client<T> client = new Client<T>(...);
}
```

I'm not sure of the correct syntax for the friend. Can anybody help?

Comment: You should read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class/4661372#4661372) to a related question. It is about overloading `operator<<`, but all of the reasoning applies here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoring the ellipses (which I assume mean "a bunch of parameters that aren't relevant to the question"), this should work:

```
template <typename T>
class Client
{
private:
    Client() {} // Note private constructor
public:
    ~Client() {} // Note public destructor

    // Note friend template function syntax
    template<typename U>
    friend Client<U> initialize();
};


template<typename T>
Client<T> initialize() 
{
      /* ... */
}
```

Notice that the friend declaration is essentially the same as the function declaration but with the `friend` keyword prefixed before the return type.

Also, the destructor is public so that users of `initialize()` will be able to destruct the returned instance of `Client<>`. The constructor is still private so only `initialize()` can create instances of it.

The above code should allow this to work:

```
int main()
{
    Client<int> client = initialize<int>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. You may want to befriend a single instantiation of the template, or you might want to befriend *all* instantiations. Finally you might not really want to befriend a template, but just a non-templated function that is automatically generated by the compiler upon instantiation of your class template...

Befriending the whole template:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
   template <typename U>
   friend MyClass<U> f();
};
```

Befriending a concrete instantiation (i.e. allowing `f<int>` access to `MyClass<int>` but not to `MyClass<double>`):

```
// Forward declarations
template <typename T>
class MyClass;
template <typename T>
MyClass<T> f();

// Definition of class template
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
   friend MyClass<T> f<T>();
};

// Definition of friend function
template <typename T>
MyClass<T> f() { ... }
```

Automatic instantiation of a befriended non-template function:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    friend MyClass<T> f() { ... } // define inline
};
```

I would recommend that you use the latter, unless the function is parametrized with other template parameters than the `T` for `MyClass<T>`.

Recommend reading: [overloading friend operator<< for template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class/4661372#4661372)

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename U> friend Client<U> initialize(.....);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make your destructor `public`. If you need to keep it `private` you need to declare another `friend` function to delete the `Client` objects that you've created.

```
template <typename T>
class Client
{
    private:
        Client() {}
        ~Client() {}

        template <typename U>
        friend Client<U> *initialize();

        template <typename U>
        friend void destroy( Client<U> * );
};


template <typename T>
Client<T> *initialize() 
{
  return new Client<T>();
}

template <typename T>
void destroy( Client<T> *client )
{
  delete client;
}

int main()
{
  auto client = initialize<int>();

  destroy( client );

  return 0;
}
```