# Some problems about class template's friend

Tags: c++, templates, friend

We have two class-templates: A and B, and a function-template f1(). Like this:

```
template< class T >
class A{};

template< class T >
class B
{
    friend class A<T>;          /* Expression 1 */
    friend void f1( B<T> &b );  /* Expression 2 */
};

template< class T >
void f1( B<T> &b ) {}

int main()
{
    A< int > a;
    B< int > b;

    f1( b );

    return 0;
}
```

**problem 1:** expression 1 make the specialization of A with argument T a friend
of the specialization of B with argument T. But how to make every 
specialization of A all friends of specialization of B?

**problem 2:** how to define f1 outside the class definition?
the code like this will generate an error:

```
undefined reference to `f1(B<int>&)'
```

**problem 3:** how to make all f1()s (who can receive all specialization of B as arguments)
friends of every specialization of B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1:

Do you really want to do it? Do you want `A<int>` to access `B<float>`? Usually you don't, but if you really want:

```
template <typename U>
friend class A;
```

Problem 2:

The problem in 2 is that you are not making the instantiation of the `f1` template a friend, but rather you are trying to make a non-templated free function `f1` that takes a `B<int>` your friend. The correct syntax to befriend a particular instantiation is cumbersome:

```
template <typename T> class B;
template <typename T> void f( B<T>& );
template <typename T>
class B {
   friend void f<T>( B<T>& );
};
```

Problem 3:

To make all specializations of `f1` a friend (again, do you really want this?), you can do the same approach as for the class template:

```
template <typename U>
friend void f1( B<U>& );
```

More on all those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661372/36565)

Comment: What's the difference between `template <typename U> friend class A` and `template <typename U> friend class A<U>`? I don't understand. @David Rodriguez

Comment: @UniMouS: If you mean the edit, fixing a typo (I think). This is one of those things that I hardly ever write, and the syntax is not that straight forward, I reviewed the other answer I wrote quite some time ago that I had *verified* with a compiler and made the syntax consistent.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your answer, I am a beginner in C++ and I don't quite understand that syntax. @David Rodriguez

Comment: @UniMouS: In this particular case, the syntax is complex enough and not really well understood in general that even experienced programmers don't get it right in the first try.

Answer (score 3):

problem 1: use

```
template <typename U> friend class A;
```

instead of

```
friend class A<T>;
```

problem 2: What expression 2 does is declaring friend a normal function taking a B, not the specialization of the function template. To declare friend the specialization for T, you need the friend clause to see a declaration of f1 and add `<>` to mark the f1 is a specialization and not an overloaded normal function, so

```
template< class T >
class B;
template< class T >
void f1( B<T> &b );
template< class T >
class B
{
    friend void f1<>( B<T> &b );
};

template< class T >
void f1( B<T> &b ) {}
```

problem 3 solution is a mix of the two:

```
class B;
template< class T >
void f1( B<T> &b );
template< class T >
class B
{
    template <typename U> friend void f1( B<U> &b );
};
```