# C++ : friend declaration ‘declares a non-template function

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, ostream

I have a problem to overload the `<<` stream operator and I don't find the solution :

```
template<class T, unsigned int TN>
class NVector
{
    inline friend std::ostream& operator<< (
        std::ostream &lhs, const NVector<T, TN> &rhs);
};

template<class T, unsigned int TN>
inline std::ostream& NVector<T, TN>::operator<<(
    std::ostream &lhs, const NVector<T, TN> &rhs)
{
    /* SOMETHING */
    return lhs;
};
```

It produces the following error message:

> warning : friend declaration ‘std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const NVector&)’ declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>
> error: ‘std::ostream& NVector::operator<<(std::ostream&, const NVector&)’ must take exactly one argument

How to solve that problem ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: A friend is not a member, and `operator<<` should not be a member. Remove the resolution in the definition header.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two different issues in your code, the first is that the `friend` declaration (as the warning clearly says, maybe not so clear to understand) declares a single non-templated function as a friend. That is, when you instantiate the template `NVector<int,5>` it declares a non-templated function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&,NVector<int,5>)` as a friend. Note that this is different from declaring the template function that you provided as a friend.

I would recommend that you define the friend function inside the class definition. You can read more on this in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661372/36565).

```
template <typename T, unsigned int TN>
class NVector {
   friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& o, NVector const & v ) {
      // code goes here
      return o;
   }
};
```

Alternatively you can opt for other options:

1. declare the `operator<<` template as a friend (will grant access to any and all instantiations of the template),
2. declare a particular instantiation of that template as a friend (more cumbersome to write) or
3. avoid friendship altogether providing a public `print( std::ostream& )` member function and calling it from a non-friend templated `operator<<`. I would still opt to befriend the non-template function an provide the definition inside the templated class.

The second issue is that when you want to define an operator outside of the class of the left hand side argument, the operator is a *free function* (not bound to a class) and thus it should not be qualified:

```
template<class T, unsigned int TN>
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &lhs, const NVector<T, TN> &rhs)
{
    /* SOMETHING */
    return lhs;
};
```

Comment: If any body is looking why there damn warning sticks around even though that's exactly what they want to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230435/how-to-fix-gcc-warning-friend-declaration-declares-a-non-template-function
Basically option 2. is the only viable one, even if it's ugly