# Can't link a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code:

```
template<typename T>
class Listoid{

  private:
    std::vector<T> list;

  public:
    typedef typename std::vector<T>::iterator iterator;

    iterator begin() {return list.begin();}
    iterator end() {return list.end();}

  public:
    Listoid(T t) {
      list.push_back(t);
    }

  const T operator [](int i){
    return list[i];
  }

  void addElem(T ne){
    list.push_back(ne);
  }

  friend T cons(T new_elem, Listoid<T> list);

};

template<typename T>
Listoid<T> cons(T new_elem, Listoid<T> list){

  Listoid<T> new_list(new_elem);
  for(typename Listoid<T>::iterator it = list.begin(), e = list.end();
        it != e; ++it){
          new_list.addElem(*it);
        }
  return new_list;
}


int main(){

  Listoid<int> lista(312);
  lista.addElem(22);

  Listoid<int> lista2 = cons(21, lista);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But i cannot compile it; i get the following error:

```
/tmp/listoid-3kYCmd.o: In function `main':
listoid.cpp:(.text+0xda): undefined reference to `cons(int, Listoid<int>)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Maybe it's really simple, but i cannot solve it. Can someone help?

Comment: Your friend function's return type is wrong, it should be `Listoid<T>`, not `T`. Though that's not the source of your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must tell the compiler that `cons` is function template not simple function. Use this syntax:

```
friend T cons <>(T new_elem, Listoid<T> list);
```

Note **<>** after function name.

Otherwise it is searching for simple function, not function template. That is linker telling you.

[UPDATE]

And do not forget to add forward declaration of your function before its friend class, so your class will know what is the friend.

```
template<typename T>
Listoid<T> cons(T new_elem, Listoid<T> list);
```

[UPDATE2]

And change your type of your function template, and add forward declaration of your class.
See:

```
template<typename T>
class Listoid;
template<typename T>
Listoid<T> cons(T new_elem, Listoid<T> list);

template<typename T>
class Listoid{
...

  friend Listoid<T> cons <>(T new_elem, Listoid<T> list);

};
```

That works for me: [ideone](http://ideone.com/sTpPX)

Comment: Curiously, this change makes my compiler (clang++) claim that friends can only be classes or functions.

Comment: Yes, i also tried with `g++` and i got the same error (friend can only be classes or functions)

Comment: See my update. I forget that function template forward declaration is needed.

Comment: Perfect! But, C++ is really difficult to me :(

Answer (score 1):

`friend T cons(T new_elem, Listoid<T> list);` is not a template, your later `template<typename T> Listoid<T> cons(T new_elem, Listoid<T> list)` is different overload of the `cons()` function. See [FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/template-friends.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to re-handle your function declaration with a template declaration and a correct return type :

```
   template<typename U> friend Listoid<U> cons(U new_elem, Listoid<U> list);
```

And rename your `typename` so it does not shadow the template type in your class template.

Comment: That will make any `cons<U>` function template specializations to be friend of any `Listoid<T>` class template specialization. This is not what OP wants. OP wants that for the same `T` `Listoid<T>` be friend to `cons<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two different declarations of `cons`, one in the `friend` declaration, another outside at namespace level. Friendship in templates is not as straightforward as it might look at the beginning, I recommend that you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661372/36565) other answer with a long explanation of the different options. In particular, if you want (as it seems) to befriend only a particular specialization of the template you will need to provide the declaration upfront, before the class template:

```
template<typename T>
class Listoid;
template<typename T>
T cons(T new_elem, Listoid<T> list);
template<typename T>
class Listoid{
   friend T cons<T>(T,Listoid<T>);
...
```

In the current form you are declaring a non-template function to be a friend. That non-template function will be a better match than the template (non-templates are preferred over templates when the types match) and the compiler will generate a dependency towards the non-teplated function:

```
int const(int,Listoid<int>);
```