# error in friend function syntax using templates c++

Tags: c++

I am writing a class representing a Matrix and encountered an error:
"expected ‘)’ before ‘<’ token" on the second to last line.

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix;

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> operator-(const Matrix<T> &self);

template<typename T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream &out, const Matrix<T> &matrix);

template<typename T> class Matrix
{
public:
    friend ostream & (operator<<<> )(ostream &out, const Matrix &matrix);

    friend Matrix (operator-<>)(const Matrix &self); //error here
};
```

Comment: [Compiles with clang.](http://rextester.com/JVM93224)

Comment: [**Read this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4661372/1322972). What platform+toolchain are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Must have been a bug with eclipse using Linux GCC.
Solved it by compiling with a different compiler.