# Linker error when operator== is a friend

Tags: c++, templates, linker, friend

The following code is a minimum code to reproduce my problem. When I try to compile it, the linker can not find `operator==` for `Config`:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"operator==(Config<2> const&, Config<2> const&)", referenced from:
          _main in test2.o
```

The `operator==` is a friend of `Config`. BUT when I do no longer declare `operator==` as a friend, the code compilers with no error.

```
template <int DIM>
class Config{
    // comment the following line out and it works
    friend bool operator==(const Config<DIM>& a, const Config<DIM>& b);

    public:
        int val;
};

template <int DIM>
bool operator==(const Config<DIM>& a, const Config<DIM>& b){
    return a.val == b.val;
}

int main() {
    Config<2> a;
    Config<2> b;
    a == b;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have missed to declare the template in the `friend` declaration:

```
template <int DIM>
class Config{
    template <int DIM_> // <<<<
    friend bool operator==(const Config<DIM_>& a, const Config<DIM_>& b);

    public:
        int val;
};
```

If you want to have a `friend` function declaration you *must use it's exact signature declaration*. If this involves template parameters these must be specified independently from the enclosing template class or struct.

---

Here's a [brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661372/1413395) explaining the several aspects of `friend` declarations in depth.

Comment: Solves the problem but I have no clue WHY I have to define it as a template explicitly.

Comment: @Michael because otherwise you're not friending your template operator, you're friending (and declaring) just some specific operator == to friend with your *class* template.

Comment: A friend function is just any ordinary function *outside* of the class that declares it as a friend. Now, just copy the friend declaration to outside the class, remove the `friend` and you will see it doesn't match the template function that you wrote. BTW, I wrote function because an operator is just a function with a special calling syntax.

Comment: So I have to tell the compiler: "Please look for a **template** and not a plain, non-template function." ?

Comment: @Michael Updated my answer a bit.

Comment: @Michael though not the same operator, the techniques for friending (and pitfalls you may not have considered) are well explained [in this answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class/4661372#4661372).