# friend operator << and private access of template class member

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend, ostream

After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661372/3893262), I made some tests and I came up with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> 
class Test {
    int val{42};

    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & flux, Test const & instance) {
        return flux << Test<char>{}.val;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << Test<int>{};
    return 0;
}
```

Using `Test<int>` in `main()`, I thought that `operator<<` couldn't access `Test<char>{}.val`. But to my surprise, GCC compiled fine.

Then, I tested with Clang and Visual Studio, and both gave me a private member error, as expected (see [GCC/Clang demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4821c10a424f2cd9)).

Which compiler is right?

Also, I'm wondering in which case one would need the **extrovert** version mentioned in the link? Or private access to `Test<U>` from within `operator<<` of `Test<T>` (when `T` != `U`)?  Do you have any practical examples?

Comment: Which version of C++ are you asking about? What versions of those compilers did you use?

Comment: I see no evidence in the standard (C++11) that this program should be considered valid, yet it's suspicious that GCC accepts what seems to be such an obvious error.

Comment: Perhaps someone misread 14.5.4/5... 11.3/2 is pretty clear and nothing contradicts it that I have found. I propose you post this on GCC's Bugzilla, then report back with an answer informing us of whatever conclusion the devs come to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Clang/VS are using the correct behavior, because if you create a new instance (as in your example) instead of using the friended instance from the parameters I believe it resets the access to be as if it's from outside.

As for the extra question, I can't think of a practical example the extrovert, but I imagine it's there for the same reason as many things in C++, to let you do it that way if you want to. Maybe use it to convert from one type to another? not sure, sorry^^;

PS sorry for the original confusion.

Comment: _"The DEMO you linked now shows basically the same error as Clang or VS"_ No, look closer!

Comment: "g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && echo "GCC OK" && clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
GCC OK
main.cpp:8:37: error: 'val' is a private member of 'Test<char>'
        return flux << Test<char>{}.val;
                                    ^
main.cpp:13:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'operator<<' requested here
    std::cout << Test<int>{};
              ^
main.cpp:5:9: note: implicitly declared private here
    int val{42};
        ^
1 error generated.

" That's almost exactly what I got form clang.

Comment: That _is_ the clang output. GCC emits no diagnostics. That's why the `echo "GCC OK"` is there - to show that the first diagnostics come from the call to clang.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Never used that site before and before the link was simply labeled as DEMO.

Comment: It wasn't very clear. I interpreted it in just the same way you did, at first.