# What is the meaning of this error `friend declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(..)' declares a non-template function`?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, friend, ostream

given that class:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::ostream;

template<class T>
class MyClass {
    T x;
public:
    MyClass(T x);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyClass<T>& m);
};

template<class T>
MyClass<T>::MyClass(T x) :
        x(x) {
}

template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const MyClass<T>& m) {
    return os < m.x;
}
```

I get the following error:

> friend declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const MyClass&)' declares a non-template function

Can someone explain the meaning of that error and how can I fix it (but I want to do that inside the class)?

Comment: @MohammadKanan but they gives him just a final answer without explanationyour question.

Comment: I added another item to the duplicate list that gives a better explanation in the answer

Comment: @M.M If I will add `template <class S> ` above `operator<<` inside the class. Can you explain what is the connection between `T` to `S` ?

Comment: There is no connection between T and S, that is the point.

Comment: @M.M This is the something that I don't understand..

Comment: It is explained in other answers already; I added more to the list

Comment: @M.M I don't see answer about this thing in the linked questions..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661372/1505939

Comment: @M.M Can you explain this "// all instantiations of this template are my friends" ?

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: @M.M What it's really say?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking sorry. It seems like a simple statement to me and I don't understand how you don't understand it, you will need to explain further what is tripping you up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172543/discussion-between-askmath-and-m-m).