# How to type custom io manipulators for use with const objects?

Tags: c++, constants, iomanip

I'm trying to lift a simple Array-io manipulator I wrote to use `std::vector`s. Here is the old signature I had been using:

```
template<typename T>
struct arr {
   const size_t size;
   T* values;
   arr(const size_t size, T* values) : size(size), values(values) {};

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const arr<T>& array);

   friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, arr<T>& array);
};
```

Now I tried to lift it like so:

```
template<typename T>
struct arr {
   std::vector<T>& vec;
   arr(std::vector<T>& vec) : vec(vec) {};

   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const arr<T>& array);

   friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, arr<T>& array);
};
```

However I am facing the following problem: I want to use `<< arr(member)` from inside a `const` declared member method. This doesnt't compile of course:

```
error: binding reference of type ‘std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IController> >&’ to ‘const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IController> >’ discards qualifiers
```

However when I change the constructor aguments and `arr::vec` to `const std::vector<T>&` I have the opposite problem and `>> arr(member)` cannot work anymore!

I was hoping that by initializing the `arr` instance as `const` I could solve this but I face the same compiler error with the following line:

```
const streamutils::arr<int> list(myVector);
```

**How can I solve this without declaring two different types for the in and out directions?**
I attempted to look at the libstdc++ source to see how it is done for `std::quoted` but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parametrize your manipulator not with `T` but with `vector<T>` itself. This way you'll be able not to bother about your vector being const or not. Also create a helper function which returns the instance of your class with corresponding template type.

```
template<typename T>
using is_vector = std::is_same<T, std::vector<typename T::value_type, typename T::allocator_type>>;

template<typename T>
struct Arr {
    static_assert(is_vector<std::decay_t<T>>::value);

    T& vec;

    // Note that arr is passed by value here because it is a temporary
    // in expressions like 'cin >> arr(a)'
    template<typename U>
    friend std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<U>, std::istream&> operator>>(std::istream& in, Arr<U> Arr);

    template<typename U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Arr<U>& Arr);
};

template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const_v<T>, std::istream&> operator>>(std::istream& in, Arr<T> arr) {
    int n;
    in >> n;
    arr.vec.resize(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        in >> arr.vec[i];
    }
    return in;
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Arr<T>& arr) {
    out << arr.vec.size() << "\n";
    for (const auto& x: arr.vec) {
        out << x << " ";
    }
    out << "\n";
    return out;
}

template<typename T, typename = typename is_vector<std::decay_t<T>>::type>
Arr<T> arr(T& t)
{
    return Arr<T>{t};
}

int main() {
    vector<int> a;
    cin >> arr(a);
    cout << arr(a) << endl;

    const vector<int> b{1, 2, 3};
    cin >> arr(b); // compile error
    cout << arr(b) << endl;
}
```

Also, consider reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class) post, it explains various ways to make friend template operators (the one I showed here is not the best and not the only possible).

Comment: the one labelled *the introvert* there is the one I am actually using in my code at the moment (the post above was stripped of the implementations).
Thanks also for the pass-by-value tip - that had tripped me up before and I never quite figured it out.

Can I leave out the `static_assert` and extra `typename = typename is_vector`...  if I make sure to only instantiate it correctly? It is a small codebase and for now I take readability (from my limited-template-knowledge perspective) over safety in this kind of situation

Comment: @sol If you are 100% sure that no one ever will instantiate this template with incorrect types then of course you can leave them out. Though apart from safety it may give you more readable errors sometimes.