# Is it possible to define operator<< for templated types?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I want to print values of STL types like `std::map`s, for example:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> t = {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, {5}}};
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This fails because `operator<<` isn't defined for these types.

If I try to define it myself, I have to also forward declare my definitions, otherwise the compilation fails with:

```
error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
        o << sep << "{" << x.first << ", " << x.second << "}";
...
note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const std::vector<T>& vec)
```

That is unfortunate because having to forward declare the methods would require using two includes for each type (forward declarations first and then implementations).

- Is there a way to define `operator<<` for templated types in a modular way?
- Is this difficulty the reasoning behind why `operator<<` isn't available for STL types out of the box?

Reference: [A working implementation with forward declarations](https://gist.github.com/yairchu/85e6821fd19379fb78c86f5f2b28a4ac)

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 isn't the reference I've linked to in the last line just that?

Comment: the link is to code that compiles fine: https://godbolt.org/z/9Prjbhed3, hence, no, its is not a [mcve] for the problem with the compiler error

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 my question instructs that if removing the forward declarations, it doesn't work

Comment: *"Is there a way to define operator<< for templated types in a modular way?"* Via argument-dependent lookup. That requires placing `operator<<` into an associated namespace, which isn't possible for `int` and `std::` types.

Comment: @dyp it works for the example but not the principle, then you wouldn't be able to use operator<< for vectors that include maps.

Comment: this is simpler if you post the code that has the error. When I have to modify the code that reproduces the error, then I might change it in such a way that it is different from your code that produces the error. Though the code actually compiles fine also when I remove the forward declarations: https://godbolt.org/z/GxThvGd1M.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 alright, edited my gist according to your suggestion

Comment: @dyp it looks like putting my definitions in namespace std actually solves the problem?

Comment: You're not allowed to put definitions into namespace `std` (with very few exceptions). A workaround is forward-declarations as you did, or using custom types like `struct MyInt{ int x; };` instead of `int`. Those custom types have an associated namespace, and the namespaces of all template arguments are relevant for ADL

Comment: Question similar to this has already been answered [Refer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class)

Comment: i don't quite remember all the reasons, but in general it is not the best idea to provide operators for types that are not your types. There is no issue with using a light-weight wrapper or tag that lets you write `std::cout << my_map_printer(t);` however

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: one of the reason is ODR (several libs defining `operator <<(std::ostream&, std::map<K, V>)`).

Comment: @Jarod42 would making the functions static work around the ODR?

Comment: Possibly, but why not just use a regular function or write a wrapper around data/stream?

Comment: @Jarod42
what do you mean by using a regular function, in contrast to an operator?
because one may be using libraries that already use operator<<

Comment: `void print(const std::vector<T>&)`. regular functions might go in namespace. operators generally go in namespace of one of its parameter (for ADL), and you cannot place it in `namespace std`...

Answer (score 1):

In your gist, the `operator<<` overload for `std::map<K, V>` is defined before the overload for `std::vector<T>`.

GCC gladly accepts your code it without raising any errors, while Clang (the one you are using I guess) outright refuses to compile it with the message you have posted, which basically says that that there's no good `operator<<` for `std::vector<T>` has been defined yet.

I should double check what the standard specifies in this situations, but my first impression is that GCC is accepting your code because `operator<<(ostream&,const std::vector<T>&)` is defined at instantiation time (which happens in `main()`, when you call `std::cout << t`), while Clang strictly considers as visible only those functions that are known at the time the template has been defined.

If you add a forward declaration for `operator<<(ostream&,const std::vector<T>&)`, it becomes unambiguously visible in `operator<<(ostream&, const std::map<K,V>)` and Clang compiles your code.

Just swapping the functions is also enough to get your specific code to build under Clang, but it will break again if you attempt to do

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::map<int, int>> u = {{{1, 2},{3, 4}}, {{4, 5}}};

    std::cout << u << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

because now Clang will not see the correct overload for `std::map<K, V>` inside the implementation for `std::vector<T>` (with GCC it will still build fine though)