# Nested function template instantiation without forward declaration compiles on GCC but not on clang

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The following doesn't compile in clang, but does in GCC ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/WGjf3v93e)):

```
template <typename K, typename V>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const std::map<K, V>& map)
{
    const char* sep = "{";
    for (const auto& x : map)
    {
        o << sep << "{" << x.first << ", " << x.second << "}";
        sep = ", ";
    }
    return o << "}";
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    const char* sep = "{";
    for (const auto& x : vec)
    {
        o << sep << x;
        sep = ", ";
    }
    return o << "}";
}

// Usage

int main()
{
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>> t = {{1, {2, 3}}, {4, {5}}};
    std::cout << t << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Who is right?

btw, I know it's UB, but putting the two templates definitions in `namespace std` makes the code compile on clang as well.

Code borrowed from [Is it possible to define operator<< for templated types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67368382/is-it-possible-to-define-operator-for-templated-types)

Comment: If you just swap the order of the `operator<<` overloads, it should compile.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes but then, if it comes to the vector of maps instead, changing the order will break it ^^

Comment: @Fareanor Sure - in that case one would have to forward declare instead. `template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const std::vector<T>& vec);`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Agreed, I said that because in the linked question, the OP didn't want to forward declare anything.

Comment: @Fareanor Ah, I see (I didn't read the link that the code was borrowed from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clang is right. You should move `operator<<`'s declaration for `std::vector` before `operator<<`'s definition for `std::map`.

In [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Template_definition),

(emphasis mine)

> For a dependent name used in a template definition, the lookup is postponed until the template arguments are known, at which time ADL examines function declarations `with external linkage (until C++11)` that are visible from the template definition context as well as in the template instantiation context, **while non-ADL lookup only examines function declarations `with external linkage (until C++11)` that are visible from the template definition context (in other words, adding a new function declaration after template definition does not make it visible except via ADL**).

Comment: I wonder what the rationale is for the difference

Comment: @Danra Rationale for the difference between Clang and Gcc?

Comment: between which declarations ADL and non-ADL lookups examine

Comment: @Danra Non-ADL examines declarations before where they're used, which works the same as non-template functions. ADL examines namespaces where the classes used as parameters are declared. In this case none of them get found, because `operator<<` for `std::vector` is declared after the one for `std::map` then it's invisible, and `std::vector` is declared in namespace `std` but `operator<<` is declared in global namespace.