# C++ << operator overloading for class with templates

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I am trying to overload << operator for my exception class. My class header file looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class FullContainerException
{
    public:
    Element<T>* elem;
    FullContainerException(Element<T>* elem):elem(elem){};
    template<typename U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, FullContainerException<T> a);
};
```

and my source file is this:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, FullContainerException<T> a)
{
    return os<<"Nie udalo sie dodac elementu: "<<a.elem<<std::endl;
}
```

in main it is called by this:

```
catch (FullContainerException<int> exception)
{
    std::cout << exception << std::endl;
}
```

When i run it i get error that it `couldn't deduce template parameter U`, but in the same project i have other class which uses the same `template<typename U>`. Header:

```
template<typename T>
class Element
{
    public:
    T name;
    Element<T>* next;
    Element<T>(T name):name(name), next(NULL){};
    template<typename U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Element<T>* a);
};
```

Source:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, Element<T>* a)
{
    return os<<a->name;
}
```

Also i tried defining the overload function inside my class declaration like this:

```
template <typename T>
class FullContainerException
{
    public:
    Element<T>* elem;
    FullContainerException(Element<T>* elem):elem(elem){};
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, FullContainerException<T> a)
    {
        return os<<"Nie udalo sie dodac elementu: "<<a.elem<<std::endl;
    }
};
```

Which worked fine. So my question is

- Why does the << operator work for the "Element" class and not for the exception class and how can i make it work (I'm not so fond on defining functions inside header file)?

Comment: You are not using `U` at all? Why the template?

Comment: I strongly suggest reviewing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class), and more specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661372/1322972)

Comment: Otherwise it shows `friend declaration declares a non-template function` error and among the other things that I tried only this solution worked.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thank you, my error was that i misunderstood the `template<typename U>` purpouse. Now everything works fine.