# C++ Operator vs. method overloading and their different behaviours

Tags: c++, methods, overloading, operator-keyword

I am currently implementing classes for labeling support in c++. However, I am a bit confused about the different behaviour of the overloaded operator and isEqual methods:

```
class Lbl
{
public:
    virtual bool operator == (const Lbl* l) const = 0;
    virtual bool isEqual (const Lbl* l) const = 0;
};

class SubLbl : public Lbl
{
public:
    SubLbl(){}

    bool operator == (const Lbl* l) const {return true;}
    bool isEqual (const Lbl* l) const {return true;}
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SubLbl* l1 = new SubLbl();
    SubLbl* l2 = new SubLbl();

    cout << (l1 == l2) << endl;
    cout << (l1->isEqual(l2)) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Why is this? How do I need to change this to get the operator overloaded as well? Why do I have to inherit "public" to have the "isEqual" method be accessable? Or is this just a typical situation for templates which I have not used (and do not know) so far?

What I am doing is implementing different SubLbl classes for the support of different type of labels I can put on objects. All (SubLbl classes) inherit from the Lbl class and should overload the equality operator due to their own equality definitions (int comparison is different to the comparison of two complex objects and even different to a double comparison). Later (in the program) I do not want to know what kind of sub-label I am currently looking at, I just want to know whether they are equal or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one:

```
l1 == l2
```

is comparing pointers. This will ony be true if the addresses of `l1` and `l2` ar ethe same.

This one

```
l1->isEqual(l2)
```

is performing a calling a member function that returns `true`.

Comment: it is worth noting that `*l1 == *l2` *would* invoke the overloaded operator.

Comment: @AlexShesterov I don't think so: the operator expect a pointer, calling `(*l1 == l2)` would do, and I don't think it is desired behaviour.

Comment: @Antonio: oh... right... I didn't notice that `*` in the signature (in place of the usual `&`)...

Comment: @juanchopanza You are right: 
In fact, l1 is a pointer and not an object of a class. By changing the command to 'code'(*l1 == l2) the overloading worked because I am now addressing the object, not the pointer. You saved the day!

Answer (score 1):

I have to say, reading better, it's a pretty tricky answer, because you are speaking about inheritance and overloading an operator.

My guess is that you shouldn't compare objects with operator== if you don't know they are exactly the same kind of class. I thing you should only define, within SubLbl:

```
bool operator == (const SubLbl& l) const {return _something_;}
```

Note I put an object of type **SubLbl** as argument. And I would avoid defining a virtual `operator==` in Lbl, especially if virtual.
The function isEqual, on the other hand, could be ok.

You can find some inspiration for different solutions here: [Making operator<< virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571611/virtual-operator)

**This is my old answer**

In the first case, you are not calling the operator you defined, but you are checking if the 2 pointers point to the same object, or better, have the same value.

To call your operator, you should have put:

```
cout << (*l1 == l2) << endl;
```

But the way you defined the operator is not recommendable. You should, for example, define:

```
bool operator == (const Lbl& l) const {return _something_;}
```

and call

```
cout << (*l1 == *l2) << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, the basic operator == function of the checks whether the classes are the same or not and returns false in the latter case. If true, the passed object is type-casted and the type-specific equality operator method (as you suggested) is called.