# Overload operator in subclass

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

tour and guided tour. Guided tour extends the tour class. I'm overloading << and >> operators in the tour class.

My tour class looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Customer.h"

using namespace std;

class Tour {

protected:
    string id;
    string description;
    double fee;
    vector<string> customerList;

public:
    Tour();
    Tour(string idVal, string descriptionVal, double feeVal);
    string getId();
    string getDescription();
    double getFee();
    double getTotalForTour();
    virtual void addCustomer(string cust);
    vector<string> getCustomers();
    virtual void display();

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, Tour &cust);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &in, Tour &cust);
};
```

then my guided tour looks like this,

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tour.h"
#include "SimpleDate.h"

using namespace std;

class GuidedTour : public Tour {

private:
    SimpleDate* date;
    string guideName;
    int maxNumTourists;

public:
    GuidedTour();
    GuidedTour(string idVal, string descriptionVal, double feeVal, SimpleDate* dateVal, string guideNameVal, int maxNumTouristsVal);
    virtual void addCustomer(string cust);
    SimpleDate* getDate();
    void display();

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, GuidedTour &cust);
    friend istream& operator>> (istream &in, GuidedTour &cust);
};
```

I want to overload these operators differently on the subclass to do something else.

I have a Vector that contains tours and guided tours.

When i loop through the vector and do following,

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tourListVector.size(); i++) {

    cout << *tourListVector[i];
}
```

It always does what's specified in tour regardless even if the object is a guided tour.

Can you please help?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4571611/812912) may help

Comment: A virtual `read(std::stream&)` and `write(std::ostream&)` invoked from your friended base-class operators will eliminate the need for overrides of the operators in derived classes. The derivations override `read` and `write` (and can even invoke the base class directly as part of its derived functionality if needed).

Comment: Can you please explain this bit more? sorry, i'm very new to C++

Comment: @Archie Any [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) will explain this and much more.

Comment: @Archie [follow the link in Ivaylo's comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4571611/812912). Loki's response in that question is about as good a summary as you're going to see in the limited space of a SO answer.

Comment: "I want to overload these operators differently on the subclass to do something else." ― no you don't. You want to override. The difference is important and you will do yourself a lot of favor by learning and internalizing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost doing the right thing, but not quite. Let's take the output case first -- the input case works just the same.

First, you should declare a

```
virtual void write(std::ostream&) const;
```

member function in your base class. The implementation might be something like:

```
void Tour::write(std::ostream& os) const
{
    os << "ID: " << id << std::endl;
    os << "Description: " << description << std::endl;
    // etc
}
```

which I assume is the sort of code you have currently in your `operator<<(ostream&, Tour&)`. Then you need to overload this in your derived class -- perhaps with something like

```
void GuidedTour::write(std::ostream& os) const
{
    Tour::write(os); // Write out base Tour info first
    os << "Guide Name: " << guideName << std::endl;
    // etc
}
```

After that, you can declare a free (i.e. non-member) `operator<<` overload for `Tour`s, which calls your `write()` member function, like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Tour& tour)
{
    tour.write(os);
    return os;
}
```

for example.

**Explanation**: Forget the fact that your current `operator<<` is a friend; it has no bearing in this case. Instead, imagine you have two overloaded non-member functions called

```
void do_something(Tour& t); // (a)
void do_something(GuidedTour& gt); // (b)
```

Since your `tourListVector` contains (I assume) `Tour*` pointers, if you were to loop through the vector and call `do_something()` on each element, the compiler would only be able to match function (a) above. That's because it has no way of knowing that some of the `Tour*` pointers might, for a given run of your programme, actually point to `GuidedTour` instances. In order to do run-time dispatching like this, you need to use virtual functions.

**Aside**: (I know this is example code, but if you're new to C++ then it's worth pointing out just in case you weren't aware :-) )

Because you're using `Tour*` pointers, you should define a virtual destructor for your base class. If you don't, the compiler won't know that it might need to destruct all the members of the `GuidedTour` class when you call `delete` on a `Tour*`. In fact, it's generally good practice to make your destructor virtual if your class includes any other virtual functions, just to save potential problems later.

Also, please don't put `using namespace std;` in a header file :-)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood right, you have pointers in your vector. So you should use key word virtual. And read about virtual methods in C++.

Comment: if I use virtual I get the error 
Tour.h:36: error: virtual functions cannot be friends

Comment: @Archie: you override a `print` virtual function and have `operator<<` call it.