# How to overload operator << for derived classes using a shared base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, virtual, subclass

I'm trying to overload `operator<<` in several subclasses.
I have a superclass called *Question*, which has an enumerated value *type*, and a string *question*.
The subclasses of this class are *TextQuestion, ChoiceQuestion, BoolQuestion and ScaleQuestion. TextQuestion* has no additional data fields. *ChoiceQuestion* has a vector of strings, to store the multiple choice possibilities. *BoolQuestion* has no additional data fields. *ScaleQuestion* has two int-values, *low_* and *high_*, for the scale.

```
class Question {
public:
    enum Type{TEXT, CHOICE, BOOL, SCALE};
    Question():
        type_(), question_() {}
    Question(Type type, std::string question):
        type_(type), question_(question) {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Question& q);
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const;
    virtual ~Question();
    private:
    Type type_;
    std::string question_;
};

class TextQuestion: public Question {
public:
    TextQuestion():
        Question() {}
    TextQuestion(Type type, std::string question):
        Question(type, question) {}
    void print(std::ostream& out) const;
    virtual ~TextQuestion();
};

class ChoiceQuestion: public Question {
public:
    ChoiceQuestion():
        Question(), choices_() {}
    ChoiceQuestion(Type type, std::string question, std::vector<std::string> choices):
        Question(type, question), choices_(choices) {}
    void print(std::ostream& out) const;
    virtual ~ChoiceQuestion();
private:
    std::vector<std::string> choices_;
};

class BoolQuestion: public Question {
public:
    BoolQuestion():
        Question() {}
    BoolQuestion(Type type, std::string question):
        Question(type, question) {}
    void print(std::ostream& out) const;
    virtual ~BoolQuestion();
};

class ScaleQuestion: public Question {
public:
    ScaleQuestion():
        Question(), low_(), high_() {}
    ScaleQuestion(Type type, std::string question, int low = 0, int high = 0):
        Question(type, question), low_(low), high_(high) {}
    void print(std::ostream& out) const;
    virtual ~ScaleQuestion();
private:
    int low_, high_;
};
```

Now, I'm trying to overload operator<< for all these subclasses and I tried using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376943/overload-operator-in-subclass)

So I made a virtual print function in the superclass, overloaded the print function in each subclass and the `operator<<` in the superclass calls the print-function.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Question& q) {
q.print(out);
return out;
}

void Question::print(std::ostream& out) const {
    std::string type;
    switch(type_) {
    case Question::TEXT:
        type = "TEXT";
        break;
    case Question::CHOICE:
        type = "CHOICE";
        break;
    case Question::BOOL:
        type = "BOOL";
        break;
    case Question::SCALE:
        type = "SCALE";
        break;
    }
    out << type << " " << question_;
}

void TextQuestion::print(std::ostream& out) const {
    Question::print(out);
}

void ChoiceQuestion::print(std::ostream& out) const {
    Question::print(out);
    out << std::endl;
    int size(get_choices_size());
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        out << choices_[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

void BoolQuestion::print(std::ostream& out) const {
    Question::print(out);
   }

void ScaleQuestion::print(std::ostream& out) const {
    Question::print(out);
        out << " " << low_ << " " << high_;
}
```

I did it exactly like in the example, but when I output my Questions, it always uses the baseclass and outputs only the *type* and the *question*. The compiler never uses the subclasses.

Comment: print is not virtual - why?

Comment: @Till it is (look at the decl in `Question`)

Comment: Show us the implementation of the print methods and the << operators.

Comment: Terminology: **Overload** means having two simultaneously accessible functions with the same name, and automatic compile-time selection based on argument types. **Override** means having a group of functions with identical argument types, and one is selected by the dynamic type of the "acting" object.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I think it was just a typo in the question talking about overloading the print method.

Comment: I have a often-overused crystal-ball that is telling me somewhere along the line you're object-slicing your derived types down to `Question` before sending them to the output iterator. Can you please post the code for the insertion operator and your *real* usage of it? Pretty-please ?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I think you made the question even more incorrect, than it was before. You cannot override the << operator, only overload it.

Comment: @WhozCraig
i've added the code of the print functions

Comment: @CMate If he could override `operator <<`, there wouldn't be a question in the first place. The title and question should reflect what the asker wants, so as to be easily found by future askers.

Comment: @JN11 Thanks, now the last thing. Show where you're actually sending your `Question` derivations to the output stream. I've still my suspicion you're stacking up your derivations in an array, vector, or otherwise sublime container of `Question`, which would facilitate the slicing I was referring to earlier. Please show how the objects your sending through your operator are defined, and the code which sends them. Thx.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I don't think definitions should be handled so lightly. We shouldn't call an actual overload an override, just because "imitating" an override is the goal of the question.

Comment: In the edit how is `type_` determined? It only appears in one place, where it's being used.

Comment: Oh, actually you do already have a virtual function. The most likely problem is object slicing. What is the type of the object used with `operator <<` in the misbehaving test code?

Comment: @WhozCraig I have a class called Memory, which saves all the Questions in a vector. I overloaded the operator<< of the Memory class, so it would go through the vector of Questions, and output each Question (Using the operator<< of Question). I use this overloaded operator<<  of the Memory class when I want to output the entire Memory to a file.

Comment: If `Memory` saves them in a `std::vector<Question>` there is where your object slicing is happening. Is that what you have? (stick with this, I think we're almost through).

Comment: Why is a user allowed to set the wrong type on a question? Use `BoolQuestion(std::string question): Question(BOOL, question) {}` to guard against it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, that's it! But I've never heard of object slicing? What exactly is it? And how can I solve it? Does my Memory class has to become a template class??

Comment: @JN11 Use references or their cousins, pointers and smart pointers.

Comment: First, read potatoswatter's answer. Then, hit the search box at the top-right corner of this page and type "[c++] what is object slicing", [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c/14461532#14461532)

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm using pointers now, but it still won't work

Comment: @WhozCraig Do I have to use a vector of Questions, and use pointers in the operator<< of Memory?
Or use a vector of Question* and use them in the opertator<< of Memory??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Only `virtual` functions allow for dispatch according to the dynamic type of an object (given the static type of a base class).
2. Only nonstatic member functions can be `virtual`.
3. `operator <<` cannot be `virtual` because it cannot be a nonstatic member function, because its first argument must be the stream.
4. You can call a virtual function from an `operator <<` which accepts a reference to the base class.

   Calling a virtual function from a non-virtual function, to preserve interface aspects which are not overridden, is called the *non-virtual idiom*.

Ah, I did not see any `virtual` upon first read but now I do. If you are not getting subclass behavior where expected, a likely culprit is slicing, where you create an object of base class type and assign it a value from a subclass object.

```
TextQuestion q( "What is hello, world?" ); // Original object
Question & qr( q ); // Reference, not another object
Question q2( q ); // Base class object with copied subset (slice) of data.

std::cout << q << '\n'; // Observe subclass behavior.
std::cout << qr << '\n'; // Observe subclass behavior due to dynamic typing.
std::cout << q2 << '\n'; // Observe superclass behavior due to slicing.
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override `operator<<` in your classes because it cannot be a member (you cannot pass `this` as the right operand).

Instead, have a virtual `print` function overriden in each subclass, and define global/nanespace scope `operator<<` in terms of it.