# Why and how to overload operator<< for printing

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend

I have written a program for implementation of stack. And I have one display function in it.

This is how I wrote display function at first:

```
template <class t>
void Mystack<t>::display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
    {
        std::cout << input[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Then I was suggested by developers to write a display function to be more generic. So I wrote display function as:

```
template <class T>
void Mystack<T>::display(std::ostream &os) const         
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= top; i++)
    {
        os << input[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

As per my understanding the benefit of writing above function is that now I have a generic display function which I can use to display data to console or to a file too.

**Question 1**: Is my understanding correct?

Now another suggestion is to write function something like:

```
template <typename T>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Mystack<T> const& d) {
    d.display(s);
    return s;
}
```

**Question 2**: What is the benefit of having above display function? What exactly will I be able to achieve by having above display function?

Comment: You can write `std::cout << d;` instead of `d.print(std::cout)`. (You may substitute `std::cout` with another output stream such as a file).

Comment: I think your question is good, but the title is a bit misleading. How about "Why and how to overload operator<< for printing"?

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: Re: question 2, yes, do it! Yet another place where it will "just work" because you did it right is logging. Using an example from one popular logger, LOG4CPLUS_DEBUG(m_logger, "stack has " << stack);

Comment: @KennyOstrom have absolutely no idea how `"stack has " << stack` works. `"stack has "` is a C-style string literal, not an `std::ostream`

Comment: Some loggers work like a stream.  That is one such case.  It's a macro. A logger stores text often used for debugging or tech support purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For question 1, your understanding is correct, but the real improvement comes from question 2's suggestion of writing:

```
template <typename T>
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Mystack<T> const& );
```

That will let anybody stream objects of your type in the same way they would stream anything else:

```
std::cout << "Hi, my stack is " << stack << ", it has size " << stack.size();
```

to any stream they want:

```
some_file << "Result of computation is: " << stack;
std::cerr << "Error, invalid stack: " << stack << ", expected: " << some_other_thing;
```

Comment: I think the main advantage of having a separate `display()` function that is invoked in `operator<<` is the possibility of using `operator<<` everywhere along a class hierarchy, writing it only once in the base class and marking the `display()` function `virtual`, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @vsoftco I don't really see the difference in writing `void Derived::display(std::ostream&)` and `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Derived const&)`. Either way, the derived class needs its own method?

Comment: yes, indeed, however for "stylistic" reasons you may want to use only `operator<<` in displaying the content, and avoid re-defining it. Furthermore, this allows some classes along the hierarchy to not override the `display()` function, so I think overall the solution is a bit more elegant. In fact, the derived classes may not choose to override the `display()` at all, and this approach will work. Otherwise, you would still need to define `operator<<` in every class along the hierarchy.

Comment: @vsoftco Derived classes could use the base's `operator<<` too, if they don't want to override it.

Comment: Just realized that I was thinking of a `friend` (or global) implementation of `operator<<`, since in general you don't want to make `operator<<` a member function. How would you do it without explicitly re-defining `operator<<` in the `Derived` class?

Comment: Thanks, indeed you're right. I guess then the only advantage of using a virtual member function is the fact that it can be hidden from the user, by making it protected, cannot see any other advantage.

Comment: why we have friend identifier here?

Answer (score 6):

Firstly - *yes*. By taking the `std::ostream&` parameter, you can output to any derived stream too, like `std::ofstream`, or `std::cout`, `std::cerr`.

Using `operator<<` allows you to, use that operator. Consider:

```
mystack<int> stackOfInts;
//...
std::cout << "Stack contents:" << std::endl << stackOfInts << std::endl;
```

It's just more idiomatic than a 'standard' function call.

Returning the stream allows the chaining of the operator, as in the above example. The chaining is effectively passing the result of a call to `operator<<` into another one:

```
operator<<( operator<<("Stack contents:", std::endl), stackOfInts ) );
```

If this overloaded call doesn't also return an `std::ostream&`, then there is no way to do:

```
operator<<( resultOfAbove, std::endl );
```

Declaring the function a `friend` allows its definition to use private members. Without this, you would have to do something like write a public getter for each private member.

Comment: why we use friend identifier?

Comment: @tanz Declaring the function a `friend` allows the definition to use `private` members. Useful if it is to print out information that is otherwise not publicly accessible. (Usually the case).

Answer (score 1):

Both display function are basically the same. The different is the way you call the function.
With first function, you call function in usual way:

```
std::cout<<"This is MyStack (with first method): ";
m.display(std::cout);      //function call
std::cout<<std::endl;
```

With second function, you call function with operator "<<":

```
std::cout<<"This is MyStack (with second method): "
               <<m   //function call
               <<std::endl;
```

But I personally prefer the second one. Since it's more familiar to me.

Comment: why we use friend identifier?

Comment: @tanz__Usually overloaded 'operator<<' function is a nonmember function eventhough you define the function prototype inside class. As you know, private data are accessible only to member function of a class. Since this overloaded function are nonmember function,  we use 'friend' identifier to this function so that it will be able to access class private or protected data.

Answer (score 0):

As with regard to **Question 2**, this is the way to go if you have a base class and lots of derived classes, and want to write `operator<<` only once, in the base class. Then, if you declare the `display()` function as `virtual` along your class hierarchy, you can choose at runtime the correct display function. That is, if you have something like

```
Derived foo;
std::cout << foo;
```

then `Base::operator<<` will call the `Derived::display()`, because it is marked as virtual and `foo` is passed by reference. This is the way to go when you have a class hierarchy and don't want to overload `operator<<` for each derived class.

This is a common trick in avoiding code duplication. See

**<kbd>[Making operator<< virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571611/making-operator-virtual)</kbd>**

on StackOverflow for more details.