# calling a pure virtual function from operator<<

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I don't know exactly why the following code compiles and works (it works well).

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    virtual std::ostream& display(std::ostream& os) const = 0;
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& lhs, const Base& rhs)
    {
        return rhs.display(lhs);
    }
};

struct A: Base
{
    virtual std::ostream& display(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << "A" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B: A
{
    virtual std::ostream& display(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        return os << "B" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    B b;
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

I am defining the `operator<<` only once inside the `Base` class, which calls the pure `virtual display` function. This scheme is usually used to avoid re-writing `operator<<` in the derived classes, i.e. define it only once in the base class then use virtual dispatch with another function (in my case, `display()`).

See **<kbd>[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f1b09a5dbc321b6)</kbd>**

Can you explain why I am able to call a pure virtual function inside the `Base` class in the implementation of `friend std::ostream& operator<<(...)`? I thought this shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: If you couldn't call pure virtual functions through a pointer or reference to the base class they wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I though one cannot "call" a pure virtual function, only overload it and call it in a derived class.

Comment: Sure you can call it, you just can't instantiate a class that has a pure virtual function.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I think I asked a stupid question :-/ Of course, you call it through the reference.... I'll take a weekend break :)

Comment: On that note, you can even provide a definition of a pure virtual function _and_ call it.

Comment: I assume the code you are showing isn't yours.  It is a common idiom to define an operator that simply forwards to a `virtual` function.  This is done to implement “polymorphic operators” because operators themselves cannot be `virtual`.  (One can also view this as a special case of the *non-virtual interface*.)  Does this make sense?

Comment: @5gon12eder yes that's the idea, the code is mine though (I mean, was just playing with this snippet after responding to a different SO question http://stackoverflow.com/a/27871137/3093378 ). I realized now that everything is OK

Comment: @CaptainObvlious can you give a simple example when you can define AND call the pure vfunc? I remember seeing some monstrosity like this ;) but cannot remember where and how it works.

Comment: @vsoftco Make the function pure in class with `= 0;`, define it out of class, and call it using a non-virtual call (with a *qualified-id*).

Comment: You define it line you would any other member function and you invoke it explicitly (as T.C. noted).

Comment: @T.C thanks, got it, although I gotta say it's extremely weird you are allowed to do this. @Captain Obvlious, I am not getting the syntax right, how do you write it inline? `virtual return_type f(params){...} = 0`? This doesn't seem to work

Comment: @vsoftco You can't do it inline.

Comment: @T.C., ok, one more thing learned for today :) Thanks to all the comments/answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are able to call the pure virtual function because by the time you call it the function is no longer pure virtual: a derived class must override it in order to stop being "abstract".

The compiler knows that you cannot instantiate class `Base` by itself. This means that you wouldn't be able to call `operator <<` on any class that does not provide a suitable override for your pure virtual function. That is why the compiler lets you make a call: it knows that there is going to be an implementation at runtime.

Note: the only way to make a call to a pure virtual function is to call it from a constructor of the base class. Since the function is pure virtual, this causes undefined behavior; modern compilers warn you about this problem.

Comment: yeah, I managed to confuse myself, I am calling it via a reference, so the usual rules of virtual dispatch apply... I am ashamed of asking this question...