# Operator << overload inheritance, why I got input from base class, instead of child class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have a class, let's call it `A`, it has only one field, `aa`. I have another class, `B`, which inherits class `A`, and instead of having the `aa` field, it also has its own field, `bb`. Now, I overloaded `operator <<` (`cout`) for both classes. I tried to use polimorphism, but it seems that polimorphism does not work properly with operators. My code shows me only `aa` field when using operator `cout` for showing the object `obj`.

I mean, do I always need to add the `virtual` word to overload the function from the base class in a child class? If so, how should I do the same with operators, operators can't be virtual ...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    protected :
        int aa;

    public:
        A(int aa) {this->aa = aa;}
        ~A(){}
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const A& obj);
        virtual void show() {cout << "a = " << aa << "\n"; }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const A& obj)
{
    for(int i=0; i<80; i++)
        os << "-";
    os << "\n";

    os << "a = " << obj.aa << "\n";

    for(int i=0; i<80; i++)
        os << "-";
    os << "\n";

    return os;
}

class B : public A
{
    private :
        int bb;

    public:
        B(int aa, int bb) : A(aa) {this->bb = bb;}
        ~B(){}
        friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const B& obj);
        void show() {cout << "a = " << aa << "\n"; cout << "b = " << bb << "\n";}
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const B& obj)
{
    for(int i=0; i<80; i++)
        os << "-";
    os << "\n";

    os << "a = " << obj.aa << "\n";
    os << "b = " << obj.bb << "\n";

    for(int i=0; i<80; i++)
        os << "-";
    os << "\n";

    return os;
}


int main()
{
    A *obj = new B(2,3);
    cout << *obj;
    obj->show();
    delete obj;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571611/making-operator-virtual

Answer (score 2):

> I mean, do I always need to add the virtual word to overload the function from the base class in a child class? If so, how should I do the same with operators, operators can't be virtual ...

Sure they can. But only member functions can be virtual, and these operators *are not members functions* - they're global functions.

In this case, you can't make them member functions (because the first parameter isn't an instance of your class). But you could create a virtual member function and have the operator call it:

```
class A
{
protected:
    virtual void print(ostream &);
public:
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const A& obj);
    // ... other stuff ...
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const A& obj)
{
    obj.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

and then override `print` instead of `operator<<`.

Comment: And if I made them member functions, what then?

Comment: @yak If you added `ostream &operator<<(ostream &os)` as a member function then you could do `*obj << cout`.

Comment: Thank you. And what about other operators, like, let's say, the `++` and `--` operators? I overloaded one of them, and I don't understand why I'm getting the seg fault with this code: http://pastie.org/private/rtsoerb0whoskzayu3ijq. I thought that class `B` inheriths all the overloaded operators from class `A`.

Comment: @yak Could possibly be because your `operator++` function doesn't return any value.

Comment: That's one thing - thank you for this. It now compiles just fine, I only needed to change `++obj;` to `++*obj;`, hm, strange.

Comment: @yak Oh, didn't notice that. Yes, in that case, after `++obj` `obj` doesn't point to a valid object, so dereferencing it (with `obj->show();`) is likely to crash. And `delete obj;` is even more likely to crash, because it no longer matches a pointer returned by `new`.