# Overloading operator<< is not working

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Employee
{
public:
    Employee(const string& fName, const string& lName, float salary) {
        mSalary = salary;
        mFirstName = fName;
        mLastName = lName;
    }

    static Employee create() {
        string input1, input2; 
        float sal; 
        cout << "Enter first name: ";
        cin >> input1;
        cout << "\nEnter last name: ";
        cin >> input2;
        cout << "\nEnter salary here: ";
        cin >> sal;
        cout << "\n";
        Employee emp(input1, input2, sal);
        return emp;
    }

    virtual void printStats() {
        cout << "===============================================\n";
        cout << "First name:\t\t" << mFirstName << endl;
        cout << "Last name:\t\t" << mLastName << endl;
        cout << "Salary:\t\t\t" << mSalary << endl;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& outFile, Employee& emp) {
        emp.print(outFile);
        return outFile;
    }


    virtual string getName() {
        return mFirstName;
    }

protected:
    virtual void print(ostream& str) {
        str << "Name: " << mFirstName << " " << mLastName << endl;
        str << "Salary" << mSalary << endl;
    }
    string mFirstName;
    string mLastName; 
    float mSalary;
};
```

In seperate class called database, I have this method:

```
void showEmployees() {
        int counter = 1;
        for (Employee* e : data) {
            cout << "\n["<<counter<<"]\n"<<e<<"\n";
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

When I use this method I just get the memory address. Also I know the implementations are in the header file (I was just lazy).

[Making operator<< virtual?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571611/making-operator-virtual)

I followed this advice here so that I can effectively insert employee into an ostream object but it just gives me a memory address...I get that returning ostream& will give me an address but I don't know what else I could do that would work.

Comment: `cout << "\n["<<counter<<"]\n"<<*e<<"\n";`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print a pointer to the `Employee`, that is why you are getting the address. Just dereference the pointer:

```
cout << "\n[" << counter << "]\n" << *e << "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

`e` is a pointer to `Employee` as defined here:

```
for (Employee* e : data) {
```

So if  you print, you print an address. If you want to print the value pointed by `e`, you need to dereference it:

```
cout << "\n[" << counter << "]\n" << *e << "\n";
//                                   ^-- here
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that, you defined your insertion operator as:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outFile, Employee& emp)
```

And you call it by passing a pointer...

```
.....
for (Employee* e : data) {
        cout << "\n["<<counter<<"]\n"<<e<<"\n";
        .....
```

---

You should redefine your operator to take `Employee` by `const&`:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& outFile, const Employee& emp)
```

And call it like:

```
.....
for (Employee* e : data) {
        cout << "\n["<<counter<<"]\n"<< *e<<"\n";
        .....
```

Also, think about [`const-correctness`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness) and add const to your `print` memeber function.

```
virtual void print(ostream& str) const;
```