# what is the C++ version of Java's instanceof? : checking, not casting

Tags: java, c++, inheritance, visual-studio-2015, instanceof

I'm currently in the middle of a project for school in which I have to "translate" a Java program into C++.

The program emulates a media library and uses inheritance. Basically, you have a media library which you can add items to. The different kinds of items you can add are Books, Movies, and MusicAlbums.

I have a class Library, which main creates an instance of, and which has a container to hold all of my items. Item is the superclass, and Book, Movie, and MusicAlbum are its derived classes.

Here's where I'm having problems translating from Java to C++:

My instructor provided "Main.cpp", and I have to write the rest of the program based off of that. I am not allowed to modify it or the assignment is invalid. However, "Main.cpp" calls

```
cout << item << endl;
```

every time that it adds an item to the media library. So, that of course sends it to Item.cpp , where I've overridden the << operator.

Now, I have to be able to figure out whether that "item" is a Book, Movie, or MusicAlbum before I write the code for outputting its data, because each one of those things needs to be printed differently.

In my Java program, I wrote something like:

```
if(item instanceof Book){
    System.out.println((Book) item); // I overrode "toString" in Book.Java
}
elseif(item instanceof Movie){
    System.out.println((Movie) item); // overwrode "toString" in Movie.java
}
else
{
    System.out.println((MusicAlbum) item; // overrode "toString" in MusicAlbum.java
```

As you can see, I used instanceof to determine which type of item it was, and then I cast the item to that derived type before passing it to println, after overriding all of the derived class's "toString" methods.

I don't know how to do this in C++. I've looked at tons of similar questions on stackoverflow and other forums, and they all either suggest things that I tried and didn't work, or they tell you how to cast the item to the derived type but not how to just -check- which derived type it is without actually changing it first.

If anyone has any insight into how this would work in C++ I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: You could use [`dynamic_cast`!!](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast). Although casts are usually seen as indicative of poor design and come at an added runtime cost.

Comment: Checking `instanceof` od `item` and casting it to `Book` or `Movie` or `MusicAlbum` makes no sense in your Java example. `System.out.println(item)` would call overriden method anyway.

Comment: Thank you P.R., and thank you too @lexicore for pointing that out. This class is kind of a java/c++ hybrid and is the first time I've ever used Java so I'm a total novice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `dynamic_cast<T>` you can attempt to cast to a derived class pointer. If it succeeds, then that's the right type. If it fails, then it's not.

`if( dynamic_cast<Book*>(item) ) { // stuff }`

C++ does offer limited compile time ways to check certain things. For example, you can check if something is a derived class with 
`std::is_base_of<base, derived>`

There is also `std::is_same<type1, type2>`

The problem is that these are compile time resolutions. Runtime-polymorphism means naturally you can't truly know before run-time what your concrete types are.

Edit: Adding some info that's probably more useful to your situation.

The line `cout << item << endl;`, what you're doing isn't going to solve your problem from what I can tell. Dynamic type identification is bad design anyways, you should avoid it generally.

No, instead you need to take advantage of polymorphism in this case. You'll want to make `operator<<` virtual. Your subclasses will have their own ways of printing data.

When `cout << item << endl;` is invoked, you won't need to figure out the type. The vtable lookup will happen for you, and you'll get the desired behaviour.

The only catch is you might need a middleman between your overload and the  free `operator>>`. Essentially you'll have a virtual operator like I mentioned, but you'll want an overload to make sure that's invoked correctly since it's a class member and not a free function.

[Look here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571611/making-operator-virtual)

Comment: this worked! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You would tend to use the `dynamic_cast` operator.

```
Book* book = dynamic_cast<Book*>(item);
if (book != nullptr) {
    cout << book->toString() << endl;
}
```

There is also `typeid(item)` which will give you a `type_info` structure, where you could possibly do a comparison, but the more efficient way to do it is to perform the type cast.  Even though you asked to not do the type cast, C++ is not Java - you shouldn't expect the same programming method.  The type cast is simply the desired way to do it in C++.

Comment: It is worth noting that some compilers will need to have RTTI (runtime type information) turned on in order to use such functionality.